# AngularJS - Removing specific array item from $window.localStorage

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, local-storage

I'm trying to make a little Angular web-app where I set items on array to $window.localStorage, then on another page I get the array and display it.

I have made a "delete" button for every array item, but when I press it, it clears the whole localStorage, not just one specific item.

**HTML**

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr ng-repeat="product in productss track by $index">
        <td>{{product.name}}</td>
        <td><button class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle shoplisticons-remove" ng-click="deleteProduct(product)"></button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**JS**

```
helloApp.controller("StorageCtrl", function($scope, $window, productService) {
    $scope.productss = productService.getData();
    $scope.deleteProduct = function(product) {
        var index = $scope.productss.indexOf(product);
        $scope.productss.splice(index, 1);
        $window.localStorage.removeItem($window.localStorage.key(product));
    };
});

//Array, add and get:
helloApp.service('productService', function($window) {
    var KEY = 'helloApp.SelectedValue';

    var addData = function(newObj) {
        var mydata = $window.localStorage.getItem(KEY);
        if (mydata) {
            mydata = JSON.parse(mydata);
        } else {
            mydata = [];
        }
        mydata.push(newObj);
        $window.localStorage.setItem(KEY, JSON.stringify(mydata));
    };
    var getData = function() {
        var mydata = $window.localStorage.getItem(KEY);
        if (mydata) {
            mydata = JSON.parse(mydata);
        }
        return mydata || [];
    };
    return {
        addData: addData,
        getData: getData
    };
});
```

Hope I was specific enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line you are deleting the whole item .

```
 $window.localStorage.removeItem($window.localStorage.key(product));
```

I believe that you want to save the array to the local storage after deleting the element.
The point is you should set the array after deleting the product to the localStorage.
You do it like this

```
helloApp.controller("StorageCtrl", function($scope, $window, productService) {
$scope.productss = productService.getData();
$scope.deleteProduct = function (product) {
     var index = $scope.productss.indexOf(product);
     $scope.productss.splice(index, 1);
     $window.localStorage.setItem('helloApp.SelectedValue',JSON.stringfy($scope.productss));
};
```

Or for more elegant solution you can add a function to your services to set the data.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're removing the whole item. Don't forget you're storing it in localStorage as a string, so localStorage doesn't know it's an array of objects.

To delete one item, you'll have to fetch the entire array from localStorage, parse it as JSON, splice the item off using the index, and set the new array in localStorage